# Compare multiple column data in two databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two identical databases, a whole heap of data was brought across from 1 to the other, and for whatever reason there seems to be no flag which indicates which is a migrated record.

What im trying to do is compare multiple fields in each database to see which records were migrated.

So for instance, DB1 may have 10,000 jobs in the job table whilst DB2 (the old one) has 2,000. I know that those 2,000 jobs are counted in the 10,000 jobs in DB1, however i cannot distinguish between the two without comparing multiple columns until i get the correct number.

I tried the following but it failed miserably and gives me the result 0:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROm Job j
FULL OUTER JOIN [DB2.dbo.job jc ON CAST(j.jobID AS NVARCHAR(20)) = jc.jobTitle
WHERE j.AMID = jc.amid
    AND j.ClientID = jc.clientID
    AND j.personID = jc.ClientID
    AND j.JobReceivedDate = jc.JobReceivedDate
    AND j.JobTitle = jc.JobTitle
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

----- EDIT -----------------------------------------------------------

The following code results in over 3  million rows being returned:

```
SELECT 
  d1.JobTitle, d1.AMID, d1.CLIENTID, d1.PersonID,
  d2.JobTitle, d2.AMID, d2.CLIENTID, d2.PersonID,
  [RESULT] = CASE 
    WHEN (d1.AMID = d2.AMID OR (d1.AMID IS NULL AND d2.AMID IS NULL))
     AND (d1.CLIENTID = d2.CLIENTID OR (d1.CLIENTID IS NULL AND d2.CLIENTID IS NULL))
     AND (d1.PersonID = d2.PersonID OR (d1.PersonID IS NULL AND d2.PersonID IS NULL))
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM  [db1].dbo.Job AS d1
FULL OUTER JOIN
 [db2].dbo.Job AS d2
    ON D1.JobTitle = D2.JobTitle
```

There are only 84,000 records in this table.

----- EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------

Changing my initial query to the below worked well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.jobID, jc.jobID, jc.JobTitle, j.JobTitle FROM Job j
FULL OUTER JOIN [Gulf-Jobs].dbo.job jc ON j.JobTitle = jc.JobTitle
WHERE j.JobTitle = jc.JobTitle
    AND j.ClientID          = jc.clientID
    AND j.personID          = jc.personID
    AND j.JobReceivedDate   = jc.JobReceivedDate
    AND j.JobTitle          = jc.JobTitle
    AND j.JobUpdatedDate    = jc.JobUpdatedDate
    AND j.JobTypeID         = jc.JobTypeID
    AND j.JobStatusID       = jc.JobStatusID
ORDER BY Jc.JobID
```

Comment: Follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441579/compare-the-value-of-multiple-columns-from-two-different-databases. Hope helpful.

Comment: `select count(*) from Job j inner join DB2.dbo.job jc on  j.AMID = jc.amid
    AND j.ClientID = jc.clientID
    AND j.personID = jc.ClientID
    AND j.JobReceivedDate = jc.JobReceivedDate
    AND j.JobTitle = jc.JobTitle`

try this

Comment: Thanks vanloc, whenever i try to run the suggested script it gives me 3million rows there are only 84,000 total in the table

Comment: Hi @OwainEsau you need data or just the count? you could always use `except` to get just the rows from table1 that are not in table2

Comment: Hi @pream the results look to be accurate, i will need the results since i am going to add in the relative ID from DB2 so i know which records were and weren't migrated. I can upload these into a temporary table via a csv, however i can't seem to add a where clause to only return values where result = 1.

Comment: @OwainEsau on your 1st block of code you are joining (j.jobID AS NVARCHAR(20)) = jc.jobTitle this is why you get 0 as count, but u join with jobtitle in second block of code. if not, your 1st code works as intended, in case if any data is null please us inull(column,'') for every column

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Pream, you were right my initial query worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer From The comment*

On your 1st block of code you are joining (j.jobID AS NVARCHAR(20)) = jc.jobTitle this is why you get 0 as count, but u join with jobtitle in second block of code. if not, your 1st code works as intended, in case if any data is null please us inull(column,'') for every column

so the query would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROm Job j
FULL OUTER JOIN [DB2.dbo.job jc ON j.jobTitle = jc.jobTitle
WHERE j.AMID = jc.amid
AND j.ClientID = jc.clientID
AND j.personID = jc.ClientID
AND j.JobReceivedDate = jc.JobReceivedDate
```